# How to remove duplicate entries in one column in listview?

Tags: c#, listview

In my app I have a `ListView` which displays two columns.  In the first column it displays groups and in the second column it displays users.

Example

```
Group1             User1
Group1             User2
Group1             User3
Group2             User1
Group2             User2
```

So what I would like to achieve is to display:

```
Group1             User1
                   User2
                   User3
Group2             User1
                   User2
```

This is my code I am using to display the info in my `listView`

```
foreach (SearchResult entry in result)
        {
            var members = GetGroupMemberList(entry.GetDirectoryEntry());

            foreach (var item in members)
            {
                lvwListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { (string)entry.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0], item })); 
            }
        }

        result.Dispose();
        searcher.Dispose();
    }
```

I am not sure what to do to remove the duplicate entries only in column 1

Comment: Why don't you add that to a List<string> first and use "contains()" before adding it to that list? Then you can add all the items from that list to the listview using a simple for or foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

You should use  :
[ListView.Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.groups?view=netframework-4.8) to replace your Groups column :

[image]